# How to change story info (Open Graph)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

[image]

I created new story. But it as you can see it looks not good. How can I remove (change) text ("Sample Score") and link (samples.ogp.me/23512374_______) and add other picture?

Comment: Why did you blur out your name? We know what it says!

Comment: Oops. It is fail. I facepalm myself))

Answer (score 0):

To change story content, you need to put opengraph meta tags in your page like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

These meta tags define your story item content. For example...

**How can I remove (change) text ("Sample Score") ?**

ANS: You can change it here:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR TEXT"/>
```

**add other picture?**

ANS: You can change it here:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="YOUR TEXT"/>
```

For more details, please see
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

And then it should work fine :)

---

To debug your page and see if you correctly implemented opengraph tags use the debugger tool here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Hope that helps